# How to configure HTTPS on an ELB application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a client application hosted on S3 with a custom domain on godaddy. Cloudfront is serving all of the http(s) requests - all of that is well and good. I have an SSL certificate through ACM. There is an input dialog on the UI that when submitted, makes a POST request to a flask application running on ELB, but this request is failing because ELB is not configured for HTTPS (i.e. chrome is blocking an HTTP request because of mixed-content). Requests to the HTTP version of the endpoint work fine, but HTTPS requests time out. How do I configure the ELB load balancer to accept HTTPS requests? I've modified the configuration of the load balancer like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dGOz.jpg but requests are still failing. Any tips? Much appreciated!!

EDIT: I've configured the load balancer with a security group that allows ingress on 443 with HTTPS but now i'm getting a "Not secure" message with Chrome. is this because the certificate is registered with a domain associated with the site and not this api? do i need a separate certificate? The error code from chrome is: err_cert_common_name_invalid

Comment: You will need the domain name of the SSL certificate attached to the load balancer to match the domain name of the API being served by the load balancer. Do you have a DNS record pointing to the load balancer?

Comment: @MarkB thanks for your reply. currently i don't have a DNS record pointing to the load balancer, how would I go about adding that? would that be a CNAME record in godaddy? (very new to this)

Comment: It would be a CNAME record, that points to the DNS name provided by the load balancer. Then you would change your website code to make requests against the subdomain you configured as a CNAME instead of going directly against the load balancer's DNS name.